# Pull th content into a td data-label attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, responsive

I'm using a responsive table style that will collapse for smaller screen sizes and display the table header before each cell.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}
table tr {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}
table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}
table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    color: red;
    background-color:#000;
  }
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  table td:before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  table td:first-child{
    color:white;
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Statement Summary</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Account</th>
      <th scope="col">Estimated arrival date</th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Period</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Account">Visa - 3412</td>
      <td data-label="Really freaking long div magic">04/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,190</td>
      <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Visa - 6076</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" data-label="Account">Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td data-label="Due Date">03/01/2016</td>
      <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
      <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The column header is represented using the data-label attribute on each corresponding table cell. In the CSS, it's called with content: attr(data-label). I'm applying this style to some pretty large tables and I don't want to have to write the data-label for every single cell in the HTML. Is there a way to pull the th into the data-label attribute using Javascript?

Answer (score 5):

Do you want the table to go from this:

```
| Account | Estimated arrival date | Amount | Period |
| ------- | ---------------------- | ------ | ------ |
|    1234 |             03/15/2001 |  $1.00 |    3rd |
|    1235 |             04/21/2002 | $12.00 |    4th |
|    4594 |             11/11/2011 | $45.00 |    2nd |
```

To this?:

```
-----------
Account: 1234
Estimated Arrival Date: 03/15/2001
Amount: $1.00
Period: 3rd
-----------
Account: 1235
Estimated Arrival Date: 04/21/2002
Amount: $12.00
Period: 4th
-----------
Account: 4594
Estimated Arrival Date: 11/11/2011
Amount: $45.00
Period: 2nd
-----------
```

**UPDATE**
Try this code:

```js
function toggle() {
  var table = document.querySelector('.my-table');
  table.classList.toggle('show-thin');
}
```

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: inline-table;
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.th, .td {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}

.th {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.td {
  text-align: right;
}

.my-table.show-thin {
  display: block;
}

.show-thin .tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.show-thin .td {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.show-thin .td:before {
  content: attr(title) ':';
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.show-thin .thin-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
<hr/>
<div class="my-table">
<div class="tr thin-hide">
  <span class="th">Account</span>
  <span class="th">Estimated arrival date</span>
  <span class="th">Amount</span>
  <span class="th">Period</span>
</div>
<div class="tr">
  <span class="td" title="Account">1234</span>
  <span class="td" title="Estimated Arrival Date">03/15/2001</span>
  <span class="td" title="Amount">$1.00</span>
  <span class="td" title="Period">3rd</span>
</div>
<div class="tr">
  <span class="td" title="Account">1235</span>
  <span class="td" title="Estimated Arrival Date">04/21/2002</span>
  <span class="td" title="Amount">$12.00</span>
  <span class="td" title="Period">4th</span>
</div>
<div class="tr">
  <span class="td" title="Account">4594</span>
  <span class="td" title="Estimated Arrival Date">11/11/2011</span>
  <span class="td" title="Amount">$45.50</span>
  <span class="td" title="Period">2nd</span>
</div>
</div>
```

My example used a class to change the values from a tabular format to a lined format. But it can be done using a media query as well. This was just easier to demo.

The trick is in placing the `title` attribute on every cell. Then using CSS to show the `title` when in thin mode.

---

[image: Wide mode]

*This shows what the table looks like in wide mode*

---

[image: Thin mode]

*And this shows what it is like in thin mode*

---

When you look at the two images you will see that the standard table format uses the term "Estimated arrival date" with on the first work capitalized. The thin version uses "Estimated Arrival Date" with all words capitalized. This is to show that the values come from different places.

In the wide mode the header comes from here:

```
<div class="tr thin-hide">
  <span class="th">Account</span>
  <span class="th">Estimated arrival date</span>
  <span class="th">Amount</span>
  <span class="th">Period</span>
</div>
```

And in thin mode it comes from the `title` attribute.

> This does not work if you try to use `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<th>` and `<td>` tags.

Comment: I changed my code to include some code that should fit your need.

Comment: My main issue is I want to apply this responsive style to some rather large tables of data and I don't want to have to go into the HTML and set a data-label or a title attribute for each cell. So I'm hoping to use Javascript to set that attribute based off the <th> content for all applicable <td>s.

Answer (score 1):

This small code jQuery copy attr "data-label" TH to TD

```
$('table th').each(function(i,elem) {
  var num = i + 1;
  $('table td:nth-child(' + num + ')').attr('data-label', $(elem).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution with jQuery, seems to work (optional: I skip over any table cells with colspans):

```
    $('.myDiv table').each(function (index, value) {
    var headerCount = $(this).find('thead th').length;

    for (i = 0; i <= headerCount; i++) {
        var headerLabel = $(this).find('thead th:nth-child(' + i + ')').text();

        $(this).find('tr td:not([colspan]):nth-child(' + i + ')').replaceWith(
            function () {
                return $('<td data-label="' + headerLabel + '">').append($(this).contents());
            }
        );
    }

});
```